# Bug in calculator

Tags: c, bison, flex-lexer

I try to learn flex and bison but my flex/bison calculator prints the wrong result. Example

```
$ ./fb1-5 
1 + 2 + 3
= 32728
```

Makefile

```
fb1-5:  fb1-5.l fb1-5.y
    bison -d fb1-5.y
    flex fb1-5.l
    cc -o $@ fb1-5.tab.c lex.yy.c -lfl
```

lexer

```
%{
# include "fb1-5.tab.h"
%}
%% 
"+"    { return ADD; }
"-"    { return SUB; }
"*"    { return MUL; }
"/"    { return DIV; }
"|"    { return ABS; }
[0-9]+ { yylval = atoi(yytext); return NUMBER; }
\n     { return EOL; }
[ \t]  { /* ignore whitespace */ }
.      { printf("Mystery character %c\n", *yytext); }
%%
```

parser

```
/* simplest version of calculator */
%{
#include <stdio.h>
%}
/* declare tokens */
%token NUMBER
%token ADD SUB MUL DIV ABS
%token EOL
%%
calclist: /* nothing */                       
 | calclist exp EOL { printf("= %d\n", $1); } 
 ;
exp: factor       

 | exp ADD factor { $$ = $1 + $3; }
 | exp SUB factor { $$ = $1 - $3; }
 ;
factor: term       

 | factor MUL term { $$ = $1 * $3; }
 | factor DIV term { $$ = $1 / $3; }
 ;
term: NUMBER  

 | ABS term   { $$ = $2 >= 0? $2 : - $2; }
;
%%
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  yyparse();
}
yyerror(char *s)
{
  fprintf(stderr, "error: %s\n", s);
}
```

What could be the matter?

Comment: Been more than a decade since I've used bison, but perhaps the `yyval` type isn't correct by default

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the action associated with `calclist`, you're referencing the value of $1, which refers to the `calclist` part of the recursive production rule. However, you never actually assign a value to `calclist` nonterminals anywhere. Did you mean $2 here?

Comment: So the O'Reilly Flex & Bison book has a typo! Thank you.